# SCSS: Change color variable depending on body class

Tags: scss-mixins

MY SCSS

```
Color Vars: 
$primary-color: red;

$body-color: $primary-color;

.standard {
color: --var(--body-color, $body-color);
}
```

Is it possible to assign $primary-color another color value, depending on body class?

I have a special page type () and all items which have the red color als a primary color now should be green.

Is there a easy and elegant way to solve this?

i need something like:

```
.standard {
    $primary-color: red;
}

.special {
    $primary-color: blue;
}
```

I have a very large css and all red items should be blue in my special pages...